# How to optimize CLS when simulated data differs greatly from real data

Tags: pagespeed-insights, cls, cumulative-layout-shift

When running https://swisswebcams.ch/webcam/1354996226 on [pagespeed.web.dev](https://pagespeed.web.dev), the result for CLS (Mobile and Desktop) is **0**. However, when looking at CLS values measured by CrUX, the values are **0,13** and **0,21**.

How can I optimize this real world CLS when I don't even know how it can result? Is it possible that CrUX might have a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed this important part of your PageSpeed Insights test:

[image: Toggle showing origin-level data is being viewed]

And if you click on the info icon you see what it means:

[image: Explanation that origin-level data is shown]

So the CrUX data you are seeing is not for that page, but for the whole origin.

However, even if that were not the case, it's entirely possible for the lower Lighthouse section of the page to show zero CLS, and the CrUX data to show CLS. This typically implies [post-load CLS](https://web.dev/articles/optimize-cls#identifying_post-load_cls_issues) that happen on scroll or interactions that aren't excluded for CLS.

Comment: OK, let's assume these are post-load CLS. What would you recommend to do in that case to be most efficient in analyzing what is causing CLS? Because the tollbar is nice, but I guess it depends on many factors (internet speed, screen size, cpu), since I always get 0 CLS with the Web Vitals toolbar as well, no matter where I click or scroll. And even with the JS API, what good does it to log it to console when I can't reproduce it?

Comment: Where is the proof of these CLS?

Comment: The best way of debugging CLS issues that are difficult to reproduce is to collect the CLS issues in the field. See this article for more information: https://web.dev/articles/debug-performance-in-the-field or use the web-vitals.js library (or another RUM solution) to collect this for you.

As I said in the answer, you might not have any CLS issues on this page, but on other pages as CrUX is showing the origin level data.